# Sagemaker Pytorch Estimator and Hydra config

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Is there any approach in which the [Sagemaker Pytorch Estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html) accepts hyperparameters such as [hydra](https://hydra.cc/) or [omegaconf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/)?